# How to count iteration on a loop

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

I am teaching myself looping in C and I wanted to know how can the user try the **password only 3 times**?

When the first time is correct it returns correct,my current loop doesn't do the intended.

```
int password = 8795, guessed = 3;

while(1) {

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Please Enter Your Password");
    scanf ("%d ", &guessed);

    if (guessed == password ) {
        printf("Correct Password");
    } else if(guessed != password) {
        printf("Please try again for the second time");
    } else {
        printf("Please try again for the last time");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try something as while (guessesLeft > 0) and inside the while loop you decrease the value of guessesLeft with one.

Comment: A pass**word**, or a pass**code**? Note: please improve the formatting of your code!

Comment: @KIM See my answer at first brefore selecting the best.:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To loop `n` times in C, use a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  /* loop contents */
}
```

In this case, replace `n` with 3. In your case, however, it makes more sense while reading the code to do as @Michiel Uit Het Broek suggested and use a while loop:

```
int guessesLeft = 3;
while(guessesLeft > 0) {
  /* loop contents */
  guessesLeft--;
}
```

To exit the loop with the password is correct, use `break`:

```
if(guessed == password) {
  break;
}
```

Comment: This is what i did int password = 8795, guessed = 3;
int trials = 0;
 while(1){
  printf("\n\n");
  printf("Please Enter Your Password ");
  scanf("%d", &guessed);
  trials--;

  if (guessed == password ){
  printf("Correct Password");
break;
 }
  if(trials ==3){
   printf("\n\n");
  printf("Too many trials");
  break;
 }

Comment: @KIM: If you want to do i that way, you need to change `trials--` to `trials++`. You start `trials` at 0, so it has to increase, or it will never make it to 3.

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean the following

```
int password = 8795, guessed;
int attempts = 3;
int valid = 0;

printf("\n\n");
printf("Please Enter Your Password");
do
{
    scanf ("%d ", &guessed);
    --attempts;

    if ( valid = guessed == password )
    {
        printf("Correct Password");
    }
    else if( attempts != 1 )
    {
        printf("Please try again for the second time");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please try again for the last time");
    }
} while ( !valid && attempts != 0 );
```

Comment: This cannot be what he meant. This code declares the entered passcode valid if it is one more than the passcode. It also does not limit you to 3 tries.

Comment: It also breaks the loop if a user enters 1.

Comment: @Linuxios  I have understood nothing. It is a valid code. What is wrong?!

Comment: I think that you mixed up "guessed" and "guesses". Also, forgot to declare one of those two. Read your code again.

Comment: @ folkol Yes I mixed up because the author asked about three attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing guessed to 3 I would add a new variable, maybe called attempts_left and initialize that to 4. Your guessed variable gets overwritten from the users input.

Your if, else, else will never get to the last else. Your first else does not need any if condition as its current condition is the inverse of the condition at the if row.

Instead of having `while(1)` you might want to have something like `while(--attempts_left>0)`. You probably do not want to have any break in the last else, instead you probably want to break the while loop when the password is right. Outside the while loop you might want to check if the while loop ended because the password was right or because the user ran out of retries.